# Select max data in interval of 1 hour within a time range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some difficulties with sql server to select max value in a column in interval of 1 hour within a time range.

My table look like this:

```
+----------+-------+---------------------+
|    Id    | Value |      TimeStamp      |
+----------+-------+---------------------+
| 02030105 | 32.20 | 2019-04-21 08:21:50 |
| 02030106 | 30.00 | 2019-04-21 08:36:40 |
| 02030107 | 30.50 | 2019-04-21 08:51:10 |
| 02030108 | 27.70 | 2019-04-21 09:31:23 |
| 02030201 | 32.20 | 2019-04-21 09:50:30 |
| 02030202 | 32.00 | 2019-04-22 10:19:50 |
| 02030203 | 31.70 | 2019-04-22 10:34:26 |
| 02030204 | 31.00 | 2019-04-22 11:33:04 |
| 02030205 | 31.20 | 2019-04-22 11:47:50 |
+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

How do I select max Value column in interval of 1 hour within a time range from
`2019-04-21 08:21:50` to `2019-04-22 11:47:50`

I want my output to be like this:

```
+----------+-------+---------------------+
|    Id    | Value |      TimeStamp      |
+----------+-------+---------------------+
| 02030105 | 32.20 | 2019-04-21 08:21:50 |
| 02030201 | 32.20 | 2019-04-21 09:50:30 |
| 02030202 | 32.00 | 2019-04-22 10:19:50 |
| 02030205 | 31.20 | 2019-04-22 11:47:50 |
+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

Comment: @Max  `DATEADD()` not working for me, I want to select max value in each hour within a time range

Comment: You want an 1 Hour of interval FROM a specific date time or the single hours ? On your example if there are a row with hours 09:21:50 (an hour from first row) is considered ANOTHER row on output ?

Comment: @Max What I mean is 1 Hour of interval FROM a specific date time. Example: 8-9 is 1 hour, 9-10 is 1 hour...starting at specific date time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery to assign a rank to each record withing groups of each records having the same timestamp (minutes and seconds excluded) ordered by value, and then filter on the top record in each group in the outer query:

```
SELECT id, value, timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, timestamp), 0) 
            ORDER BY value DESC
        ) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=54df9c48d5877620e8e39207e90ea160)**:

```
     id | value | timestamp          
------: | :---- | :------------------
2030105 | 32.20 | 2019-04-21 08:21:50
2030201 | 32.20 | 2019-04-21 09:50:30
2030202 | 32.00 | 2019-04-22 10:19:50
2030205 | 31.20 | 2019-04-22 11:47:50
```

---

If you want the average value within each 1h range as well, then:

```
SELECT id, value, timestamp, avg_value
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, timestamp), 0) 
            ORDER BY value DESC
        ) rn,
        AVG(value) OVER(
            PARTITION BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, timestamp), 0) 
        ) avg_value
    FROM mytable t
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm testing. Now How do I select average value in interval of 1 hour within a time range?

Comment: Sorry for bothering, Can you help me one more time? How do I select average value within each 5 minutes range as well?